# Is it possible to add a new element to top of Map?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to add a new element to top of Map without sorting?

Like as `unshift()`?

Because Map is it like a object, I each time sort object after adding operation.

I have done this like that:

```
let map = new Map();

map.set(1, { id: 1 });
map.set(2, { id: 2 });
map.set(3, { id: 3 });
map.set(4, { id: 4 });

let mapCopy = new Map();


for (let i = map.size; i > 0 ; --i) {
    mapCopy.set(i, map.get(i));
}

console.log(map);
console.log(mapCopy);
```

Comment: A Map preserves insertion order. So, I guess you can only re-create it.

Comment: What do you mean by "top of Map"? Where is the top and bottom of the Map? A Map is not meant to have any of these. It's a key-value pair data structure.

Comment: I mean when I do set() I need insert of top of object, like in list

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek the "top" would be the beginning. Maps *do* preserve insertion order. It's part of the spec.

Comment: @VLAZ yeah I know, it just sounds weird to me. I personally wouldn't rely on the order of keys in a Map. If the order was important for me, I would consider a different data structure.

Comment: Could I revert Map by keys (number)?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek since the order is guaranteed by the spec, you can safely rely on it. As long as you're sure no changes would happen while you use it.

Comment: @OPV again, you have to re-create it. If you insert all current keys again, they'd follow the new order. Or you can make a new Map. In either case you'd get a new order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) preserves the insertion order of keys by specification:

```js
const map = new Map();

map.set(3, "gamma");
map.set(1, "alpha");
map.set(2, "beta");

print(map);

function print(map) {
  for ([key, value] of map.entries()) 
    console.log(`${key} - ${value}`)
}
```

If you want to move something to the end, it has to be the last inserted item. You can "move" by deleting and re-adding:

```js
const map = new Map();

map.set(3, "gamma");
map.set(1, "alpha");
map.set(2, "beta");

moveToEnd(map, 3);

print(map);

function print(map) {
  for ([key, value] of map.entries()) 
    console.log(`${key} - ${value}`)
}

//modifies in-place
function moveToEnd(map, key) {
  //save value
  const value = map.get(key);
  //delete
  map.delete(key);
  //re-insert
  map.set(key, value);
}
```

Note that you must delete, otherwise it doesn't work:

```js
const map = new Map();

map.set(3, "gamma");
map.set(1, "alpha");
map.set(2, "beta");

moveToEnd(map, 3);

print(map);

function print(map) {
  for ([key, value] of map.entries()) 
    console.log(`${key} - ${value}`)
}

//modifies in-place
function moveToEnd(map, key) {
  //save value
  const value = map.get(key);
  
  //don't delete
  
  //re-insert
  map.set(key, value);
}
```

Another option is to re-create the entire Map and enforce the new insertion order:

```js
const map = new Map();

map.set(3, "gamma");
map.set(1, "alpha");
map.set(2, "beta");

const newMap1 = moveToEnd1(map, 3);
const newMap2 = moveToEnd2(map, 3);

print(newMap1);
console.log("------")
print(newMap2);

function print(map) {
  for ([key, value] of map.entries()) 
    console.log(`${key} - ${value}`)
}

function moveToEnd1(map, key) {
  //create a new Map from the old one
  const result = new Map(map);
  
  //save value
  const value = map.get(key);
  //delete
  result.delete(key);
  //re-insert
  result.set(key, value);
  
  return result;
}

function moveToEnd2(map, key) {
  return [...map.entries()]                        //get all entries
    .filter(([k,]) => k !== key)                   //remove all but the key that would be last
    .reduce(                                       //create a new Map inserting all other entries
      (acc, [key, value]) => acc.set(key, value), 
      new Map()
    )
    .set(key, map.get(key));                       //add the last entry
}
```

However, a move to front means that you have to shift everything else to the front. Again, you can do the same as before - either move the entries in-place by deleting and re-adding the keys:

```js
const map = new Map();

map.set(3, "gamma");
map.set(1, "alpha");
map.set(2, "beta");

const newMap1 = moveToFront(map, 1);

print(map);

function print(map) {
  for ([key, value] of map.entries()) 
    console.log(`${key} - ${value}`)
}

function moveToFront(map, key) {
  //materialise all entries, because the iterator provides a live view
  const entries = Array.from(map.entries());
  
  //move to the back
  for (let [k, v] of entries) {
    //skip moving the target key
    if (k === key) continue; 
    
    //delete
    map.delete(k);
    //re-insert
    map.set(k, v);
  }
}
```

Or re-create the map with the new order. Note that if you insert the desired key in front, you can just use `set` again with it and it won't move, as long as there is no `.delete()` called for it, which makes the re-creation easier:

```js
const map = new Map();

map.set(3, "gamma");
map.set(1, "alpha");
map.set(2, "beta");

const newMap = moveToFront(map, 1);
print(newMap);

function print(map) {
  for ([key, value] of map.entries()) 
    console.log(`${key} - ${value}`)
}

function moveToFront(map, key) {
  return new Map([
    [key, map.get(key)], //key-value to be in front
    ...map               //merge with the entire map
  ]);
}
```

As for actually *adding* instead of moving - the same applies, you can either shift everything in the map or just re-create it. Assuming you want to treat a repeat inset as "move to front", then you can do something like this:

```js
const map = new Map();

map.set(3, "gamma");
map.set(1, "alpha");
map.set(2, "beta");

addToFrontInPlace(map, 4, "delta");
print(map);
console.log("-------");
addToFrontInPlace(map, 1, "new alpha");
print(map);

function print(map) {
  for ([key, value] of map.entries()) 
    console.log(`${key} - ${value}`)
}

function addToFrontInPlace(map, key, value) {
  //add new value
  map.set(key, value);
  
  //materialise all entries, because the iterator provides a live view
  const entries = Array.from(map.entries());
  
  //move to the back
  for (let [k, v] of entries) {
    //skip moving the target key
    if (k === key) continue; 
    
    //delete
    map.delete(k);
    //re-insert
    map.set(k, v);
  }

}
```

```js
const map = new Map();

map.set(3, "gamma");
map.set(1, "alpha");
map.set(2, "beta");

const newMap1 = addToFrontNewMap(map, 4, "delta");
print(newMap1);
console.log("-------");
const newMap2 = addToFrontNewMap(newMap1, 1, "new alpha");
print(newMap2);

function print(map) {
  for ([key, value] of map.entries()) 
    console.log(`${key} - ${value}`)
}

function addToFrontNewMap(map, key, value = 7) {
  //exclude the entry from the old map, so it doesn't overwrite the value
  const entries = [...map.entries()]
      .filter(([k,]) => k !== key);
      
  return new Map([
    [key, value], //key-value to be in front
    ...entries    //merge with the entire map
  ]);
}
```

Comment: Checout my question, I shared my sample

Comment: Your sample works for reversing order. Is there something more specific you need to do?

Comment: I see it works buy Angular still renders by default order

Comment: Maybe Angular sorts the keys before displaying this. I'm not sure what you can do, since I'm not familiar with Angular. In plain JS, you should be able to just extract the values with `Array.from(map.values())` and then the array will be in the correct order. Or you can set up a system where you get the keys (`Array.from(map.keys())`) which will also preserve the order and use those to lookup the values. But I'm not sure what facilities Angular provides - there might be something that either does these or alternatively uses the order of the map provided.

Answer (score 1):

The keys in Map are ordered. Thus, when iterating over it, a Map object returns keys in order of insertion.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map